# Discord.py - on_command_error() no longer fires

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The `on_command_error` event had always worked for me in the past. Today I tried to add the `on_member_update` event to my bot, which also doesn't respond. I was troubleshooting by making sure my other events still worked, and they all do - except for `on_command_error`. I've removed all the new code added since it worked as expected and it still doesn't want to fire when I call an invalid command. For instance, my custom `on_message` event instantiated just above `on_command_error` works as expected, even with new changes.

Here's the block in question:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        if ctx.prefix != bot.config.get('admin_prefix'):
            auth = ctx.message.author
            text = "Sorry <@{}>, I don't understand. Try `!help` for a list of commands I can respond to."
            await ctx.send(text.format(auth.id))
    else:
        raise error
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for reading!

Comment: even the first line is not executed? Are your commands being executed?

Comment: Correct, the print statement isn't executed, but my correct commands are executed as expected and other events that are established in the place as this event are also responsive.